# Fetch audio and pronounce word - word to speech in Extjs

Tags: extjs, speech

How can I implement word to speech?

Let's say that I have a textfield and a button. I would like to have word entered in the textfield pronounced in English.

In addition, is it possible to fetch only audio pronunciation from Merriam-Webster online dictionary  [www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stack](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stack) and play it without opening the page?

Or, maybe from Longman online pronunciation dictionary https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/overflow?

I've noticed that the path to word in dictionary has constant pattern - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ + word, as given in the screenshot.

So, my question is: is it possible to extract only audio file (.mp3) and play it without opening the page?

[image]

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 300,
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'word',
                fieldLabel: 'Word',
            },{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Pronounce',
                listeners: {
                click: function() {
                    //PRONOUNCE THE WORD
                    // ...
                    // ...;
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the html include the following:

```
<script src='https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js'></script>
```

and the fiddle code is following:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.application({
            name: 'Fiddle',

            launch: function () {
                Ext.create({
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                    width: 300,
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'word',
                        fieldLabel: 'Word',
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Pronounce',
                        listeners: {
                            click: function () {
                                const speechText = this.previousNode().getValue();
                                if(speechText) {
                                    responsiveVoice.speak(speechText);
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Arthur Rubens. I am very curious about the fetching pronunciation audio file. Could you please consider the second part of my question?

Comment: I have used https://responsivevoice.org/ api, the first one I have found in google search. The listed APIs could not find, I think you can easily do it yourself..

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how I could do it myself. But, I think that I didn't mean using any API, but simple to fetch file from the given address and then plat that file. I updated my question and added more details.

Comment: So, do you want to play some mp3 file in js or you want pragmatically speech the text in the text field?

Comment: Firstly, I want to concatenate the fixed string (address)  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ and what I have in that text field (If in text field there are two words, '%20' should be used, for example for 'get up', I should get the following address: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20up).  And second, I would like to extract mp3 file included in the web page of that address (if there is one) and play it.